# How to achieve 57 PWM outputs most easily and cheaply

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm, i2c, led-strip

I need to light up 19 RGB LED strips, which it seems would require 19*3=57 PWM outs and 57 transistors.  The transistors aren't an issue, but of course the 57 PWM's is.  Most micro controllers simply don't have that many.

How can I do this more simply?  Is there some kind of device I can get that would let me just pass data to it, perhaps over I2C, and it would control many PWMs? Is there another solution I haven't considered?  Maybe whatever is used to control those 8x8 RGB LED dot matrixes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Serial in, parallel out shift registers with SPI?

Comment: Is this a commercial job? ie: you will spend money to save time, and reliability is important? Or is it a home experiment? Do you have a preferred MCU (AVR, PIC, ARM, etc)?

Answer (score 6):

Daisy chain 3 of these ICs ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5947.pdf)) and control them via SPI. They are designed for driving LEDs.

Adafruit has dev kits if you want to play with it:

http://www.adafruit.com/product/1429

Comment: NXP has a lot of these as well, but with I2C interfaces instead.  Also very easy to use.

Comment: This is probably your fastest in terms of getting something up and running right away. The devices themselves aren't terribly cheap but they're not bad either. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any FPGA with a high enough pin count, basic PWM's are very simple in terms of logic design and usage.  Add in a soft CPU and you should be able to fit the whole thing into a Xilinx XC6SLX9 in a QFP144 package, i.e. easily hand-solderable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Cypress PSoC is well suited for this. [This PSoC Sensei blog post](http://www.cypress.com/?rID=40091) describes how to achieve 52 hardware 8-bit PWM outputs with a single PSoC3 or PSoC5. The additional ones could be achieved with a $1 PSoC4 acting as a slave over SPI or I2C.

If you haven't heard of PSoC before you might want to take a look; they're 8051 or ARM Cortex M0/M3 cores with some programmable logic beside them. There's also a variant with BLE radio built in.

Not affiliated with Cypress, just a pretty happy customer with their PSoC4 and 5LP devices.